# Linux Equivalent to Windows Service Functions?

Tags: linux, api, service

I'm trying to find the Linux equivalent to [Windows Service Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For example, Windows has `ServiceMain` for the entry point, `SetServiceStatus` to set a status, `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler`, and `HandlerEx` to respond to control codes such as start, pause and stop requests, etc.

I checked in W. Richard Steven's [Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/), but I guess its a bit dated for the task. Searching for "linux service api" and "linux ipc service start stop" (and similar) are producing some http and database results, but nothing too useful.

Would anyone know the C interface for writing Linux service programs?

Answer (score 2):

Linux services differ much:

- You develop a script (rarely binary) to handle start/stop/status
  command-line parameters (to start Your standalone Main() app/process or to do anything
  else)
- "registration" is done by putting that script into
  /etc/rc.d/init.d/ and creating corresponding
  /etc/rc.d/rc{level}.d/S{order} symbolic link(s)
- there is no
  out-of-the-box support/idea/paradigm of service-dependencies or
  auto-restart

If You run:

```
/sbin/service --status-all
```

it'll run /etc/rc.d/init.d/ scripts with "status" parameter

Comment: Thanks Vlad. How do you pause and stop a service? I was not able to find anything on pause, and stop appears to be a kill (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html). Surely killing a process is bad since it could leave data is an inconsistent state.